# How to set callback after the instance of Tabulator is created?

Tags: tabulator

I am using Tabulator and want to listen the table editing event. I checked the callback *dataEdited* and found all the examples set the callback function when creating the instance, like *new Tabulator('#samplediv',{dataEdited:function(){...}})*.

However, I need to set the callback in a sub-function after the instance created like:

```
const table=new Tabulator(......)

function SomeSub(){
// how to set dataEdited of table here?
}
```

I tried table.dataEdited=function(){} that does not work.

I don't know if it's a real problem for a skilled programmer but it really confused me. Thank you so much for any comments.

Comment: FYI, as of Tabulator 4.8 dataEdited is changed to dataChanged [Note](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/deprecated#callbacks). In either case the callback is tied to the table. What do you want to do with the callback? Why can't you put the function in the dataChanged(Edited) callback?

Comment: Thanks for notification. I will use dataChanged instead. But my question is still like I don't know how to set this callback in a sub-function after the table created. I need to use some local variables defined in the sub-function. Also, there are lots of data updating out of this sub-function that I don't want the dataChanged event to be triggered, but only in the sub-function I need to listen the data change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change a callback in Tabulator after it has been instantiated, but you can simply call another function from inside the callback.

If you are only looking to track user edits, rather than all changes to data, then the ***cellEdited*** callback may be a more appropriate choice.

```js
function externalFunction(cell){
    do a thing;
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    cellEdited:function(cell){
        externalFunction(cell);
    },
});
```

If you want to be able to change the nature of the function called, then you can just add the function on an external object, and then change it any time you want.

```js
//define initial function holding object
var functionHolder = {
    externalFunction:function (cell){
        do a thing;
    }
}

//create your table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    cellEdited:function(cell){
        functionHolder.externalFunction(cell);
    },
});

//...

//some time later redefine the function
functionHolder.externalFunction = function(cell){
    //do something different
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the external object works on my situation. I am now just doing it by some stupid way like to re-create the table in the function... Every time calling this function, the existing table will be removed and be instantiated again with the callback function defined.